# Problem with Embedded R Execution: SQL Interface (ORE)- more simple

Tags: sql, r, xml, plsql, oracle12c

As I've explained completely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896434/problem-with-embedded-r-execution-sql-interface-ore), I'm new to ORE and I'm expected to work with it. I'm going to work with SQL interface which is included using of functions like rqEval, rqTableEval and so on.
I've faced an error by executing below script in SQL which is one of the simplest examples:

- first I created the script:

  ```
  begin 
  sys.rqScriptCreate('Example5',
  'function(){
  "Hello!"}');
  end;
  ```
- Then I ran it:

  ```
  select value from  
  table(rqEval( NULL ,'XML','Example5'));
  ```

As the result of executing, below output is returned:

> A table of a row and a column with "(HUGECLOB)" as value

Now when I click on that value twice to show XML output, below error will display:

> ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value

The reason I tried this one was that I assumed the raised error could be because of some unknown mistakes or problems in script (hence that script had executed in author's machine). By the way I made decision to try with the simplest one.

I really have no idea. Please help me